# 9 volts on a neutral wire with the switch off

Tags: electrical

Light switch has 123 volts but light not working

installed a new light fixture still does not work

meter on ground and neutral shows 9 volts with the switch off or on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That just sounds like phantom voltage from the wire not being connected.  Sounds like the neutral is not complete back to the panel.

Comment: Did you double check to ensure the bulbs aren't burnt out?

Comment: "meter on ground and neutral shows 9 volts " Are you saying you're reading 9V BETWEEN ground and neutral? When you say the switch has 123 volts, is that into the switch or out? Having either conductor bad could cause this. If you check for continuity between ground and neutral do you have it?